Security concerns of FF3 for in-place encryption
There have been publicized attacks that break FF3 for small domains, specifically "Breaking the FF3 Format-Preserving Encryption
Standard over Small Domains" by Durak & Vaudenay. However, these attacks generally seem to require chosenplaintext.
Are there any attacks or security concerns when only the ciphertext is available to an attacker, e.g. when a DB with encrypted values gets stolen and no chosen plaintext attacks are possible?
The background of this question is that I see a general dismissal of FF3 for DB encryption while I wonder if the security concerns are warranted if the attack scope is - or can be - limited.
[edit: I've changed this question to read chosen plaintext instead of known plaintext - if there are any answers that assume known plaintext then please comment and I'll change it back]

The only insurmountable issue with using Format Preserving Encryption in the context of database encryption is that, for a given entry in the database, the plaintext to ciphertext relation is a bijection. One consequence is that for someone with write access to an entry of a database and access to the encrypted database, it's possible to check a guess of the plaintext for that entry.
For the rest, proper FPE does the job it's supposed to do. The problem in FF3 described in the Durak & Vaudenay attack

is specific to FF3 (or at least similar FPE constructs using Feistel ciphers for a small domain)
is believed corrected in FF3-1 of NIST SP 800-38G rev. 1 draft
requires chosen plaintext and tweak; that is in a database context where the tweak encodes which entry is encrypted, the ability to encrypt data for any entry. No issue that I can imagine with a single disclosure of a database at rest, even assuming known plaintext for most entries.

I guess the reasons pure FPE is not much used for database encryption are

FPE does not provide integrity
databases increasingly integrate authenticated encryption, making FPE moot
databases increasingly allow binary data

